# angular $q binding this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am having trouble with binding `this` inside a promise. I have the following function in angular service:

```
this.database_view_settings = {'habal':'1'}
this.init = function(){
console.log("1",this.database_view_settings)
return $q((resolve, reject) => {
console.log("2",this.database_view_settings)
    AuthenticationService.getToken().then(function(token){
    $http.get('/api/user/settings/database_view/get',{headers:{'id_token':token}})
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log("3",this.database_view_settings)
        this.database_view_settings = data;
        console.log("login",this.database_view_settings)
        resolve(this.database_view_settings)
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
        reject(data)
    });
    }.bind(this))


    })
}.bind(this)
```

My problem is that while at `console.log 1 and 2` I see what I want to `{'habal':'1'}` at `console.log 3` I get an `undefined` and I don't understand why.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Since you obviously use ES6, then you should use arrows - they are there exactly for that - for all promise callbacks. The snippet is badly formatted and it's not possible to say what's where. But unless you've done `.bind(this)` to each and every callback (and you didn't), you will inevitably lose lexical this at some point.

Comment: Plus it looks like you fell into [The Forgotten Promise](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#the-forgotten-promise:8f173b15e2d19515fdc8ce931ae539c0) anti-pattern.

Comment: The [`.success` and `.error` methods have been deprecated and removed from AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339). Also there is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q(resolve,reject)` as the $http service already returns a promise.

Comment: I read up on the arrow thing, should've done earlier ... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes the comments added to your question into account:

```
this.database_view_settings = { 'habal': '1' };

this.init = () => AuthenticationService.getToken()
  .then((token) => $http.get('/api/user/settings/database_view/get', { headers: { 'id_token': token } }))
  .then((data) => {
    this.database_view_settings = data;
    return data;
  });
```

Then, anywhere else:

```
this.init().then((data) => {
  // do your stuff with data
}).catch((error) => {
  // oops...
})
```

Comment: Much more readable, than my code, and also it works. I had to change one thing: `this.database_view_settings = data.data` is what gives me the data I got in my version (in yours `data` was the whole http response).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue for your particular problem is because you didn't bind `this` to your `$http.get` success function. That being said, this is really a lot of binding if your aim is to continuously keep passing the reference of `this` to nested functions. You can alternatively use something like `var _this = this` in the outer function and reference the `_this` variable in all your nested functions. Also, as was suggested by the comments, using arrow function will automatically bind this, to make for cleaner code.

Finally, regardless of the changes, you do not need to bind `this` on the main `this.init` function. The `this` for properties of an object are bound to the object itself, and in this case the object is `this`.